# Overlaying content and making it responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three boxes which are slightly overlaying a background image which is set to the size of the view port. This is what it looks like when scrolled down a little: 
[image: code pen demo]
I have achieved this by putting a wrapper around all the content except the background image then positioning it absolute. The problem with this is that as the viewport gets longer all the content starts to shift upwards onto the the background image. I only want the boxes to be slightly overlaying the image. But I also want it to be responsive without having to write a tone of media queries to keep it where I like it. Can you show me a better solution?

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/gGjGjJ

```css
#full_width{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   z-index: 100;
   background-color: grey;
}

#full_img{
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422360902398-0a91ff2c1a1f?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=2516&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box{
   margin: 2rem 0;
   padding: 1rem;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   -moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   box-shadow: -5px 5px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

#content_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="full_width">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            NAVIGATION
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="full_img"></div>

<div id="content_wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="box">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volutpat.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="box">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volutpat.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="box">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volutpat.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h2>another section</h2>
         
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volut. patLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volutpat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h2>another section</h2>
         
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volut. patLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec vehicula justo, vel tristique nibh. Sed eleifend eleifend augue. Maecenas at tempus tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam auctor enim vel nisl pellentesque volutpat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use positioning, use a negative `margin-top` on that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `position: absolute;` on `.content-wrapper`, use `margin-top` and set the value to `-100px`. This will move the div up and overlay it on the div above.

```
#content_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```